# set different colors to some different circles

Tags: java, colors

i have two circles (want to have some more in the future) and want them to have different colors. At the moment, the color is set with:

`public static Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.GREEN);`

The Problem is that every new Circle I create has this color too. 
How can I set new colors for different new circles?

This is where I instantiate the circles (in the constructor):

```
c1 = new Circle (165, 350, 33);    
c2 = new Circle (200, 200, 33);
p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
p1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

And this is where I call the draw in my "onDraw()":

```
canvas.drawCircle(lerpX, lerpY, c1.getR(), p);
canvas.drawCircle(c2.getX(), c2.getY(), c2.getR(), p);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you paste code where you are creating circle

Comment: java.awt.Paint is an interface. Is this some other Paint class that you have built

Comment: The use of p1 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah now i found my problem! I just forgot to call p1 in drawCircle of the c2! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it.  Almost procedural but it will work.

Define your color

```
p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
//draw shape
```

Define next color

```
 p.setColor(Color.RED);
 //draw next shape
```